# How to get string and hashmap mixed value inside a hashmap

Tags: android, api, android-volley

I'm using volley and trying to make request to API that I'm working on. Json Request should be like this format.

```
{
    "name": "API name",
    "param":{
        "email": "user@mail.com",
        "password": "password"
    }
}
```

I've tried to use hashmap but I don't know how to put

```
<string string> 
<string, hashmap>
```

this is getting complicated.

Now, how should I put these values in hashmap and convert it to JSONObject and send request to server.

If this is not the way it should be done, then what should I use instead?

Comment: Use org.json library ex usage : JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(); JSONObject param = new JSONObject(); param.put("email","blhablah")
obj.put("name", param);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HahMap can not be used for JSON serialization, I suggest you to use org.json (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json)

Ex:

```
     JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
     JSONObject param = new JSONObject();
     param.put("email","blhablah");
     param.put("password","blhablah");
     jsonObj.put("name", "apiName");
     jsonObj.put("param", param);
     System.out.println(jsonObj.toString());
```

This will give you the json, like follwoing :

**{"param":{"password":"blhablah","email":"blhablah"},"name":"apiName"}**